# Why does gf does not work for vim but ctrl+] works?

Tags: linux, vim, vi, ctags

I have a file e.g. `a.pl` that has this method call:

`add_location(@crew);`

The actual definition is in the same file. If I do: `CTRL + ]` the cursor jumps to the definition. If I do: `gf` I get:
`E447: Can't find file "add_location" in path`

If I do `:pwd` I get the current working directory. What path is the complaint about? The function definition is in the same file.

Answer (score 6):

The `<C-]>` command goes to the *tag* under the cursor; you seem to have a valid tags database (i.e. have run `ctags` before) and there is a tag named `add_location`.

The `gf` command goes to the *file* under the cursor, i.e. it treats `add_location` as a filename (possibly appending a suffix like `.pl` (see `:help 'suffixesadd'`), and searches for that in the directories specified by `'path'`.

So, basically, you're using the wrong command for the job; `<C-]>` is right. Note that if the location is in the same file, you could also use the `*` command to go to next matches; this is useful for when you have no tags database and therefore cannot use the more powerful `<C-]>` command.

Comment: So you mean that `gf` would work only if the definition was in a different file?

Comment: `gf` has nothing to do with definitions, it only deals with _file names_, e.g. if you had `foo.txt`, it would open that file. Why should there be two commands that do the same? What you're looking for is `<C-]>`.

Comment: So `gf` would just open the file that included the definition? Because this is what I thought

Comment: `<C-]>` does that, too; you can use `gg` or `G` if you want to move somewhere else. Read up `:help gf` if you don't believe me :-)

Comment: It is not that I don't believe you.I still not sure I understand what you are saying. `C -]` opens definition in the same *or different file*? And `gf` you say also. So `gf` should do what I ask in my OP? I am sorry I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: As I said, only `<C-]>` considers definitions, `gf` is purely about files, it does not consider definitions, function names, whatever, it's just basically `:edit <cfile>`.

Comment: Ok. I see what you are saying. `gf` tries to find an `add_location.pl` file in the path. So what is the `path` that `gf` looks? The `:pwd`?

Comment: @Cratylus, try `:help gf` and `:help ctrl-]`.

Comment: @Cratylus - if you are curious what `path` is then try `:set path?`.  If you're curious how it is used, try `:help path`.  It typically includes the current working directory but doesn't need to.